# Text from an english book

Tags: meaning-in-context, quotations

I am reading a book titled  " The man who loved only numbers", the author is : Paul Hoffman. I encounter a problem in understanding some lines, would some one help me ( I think there is an indirect meaning behind these lines)

There was a young man who said "God

Must find it exceedingly odd

To think that the tree

Should continue to be

When there's no one about in the quad."

"Dear Sir: Your astonishment's odd;

I am always about in the quad.

And that's why the tree

Will continue to be

Since observed by, Yours faithfully, God.”

Note that, by googling, I find this is a quote for  Ronald Arbuthnott Knox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his **first stanza**, Ronald Arbuthnot Knox **sets the scene**

> There was a **young man** who said "God
>   Must find it exceedingly **odd**
>   To think that **the tree**
>   Should continue **to be**
>   When there's no one about in the **quad**."

A **young man** is thinking about a **quad** that he is familiar with

> A **quad** or **quadrangle** is an area surrounded on four sides by buildings in an **academic** setting and usually part of a larger **campus**

from this one can infer that the young man may be a **student** or **scholar**.

The question is asked whether the tree should **be** / **exist** or not if no one is present. The reference is not to **a tree** but ***the tree***.

> metaphorically **the tree** is an allusion to [**the tree of knowledge**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_the_knowledge_of_good_and_evil)

This is a **philosophical question** along the lines of

> [**If a tree falls in a forest**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest) *(note parallel using tree)*

In his **second stanza**, Knox writes **God's reply**

> Dear Sir: Your astonishment's odd;
>   I am **always about in the quad**.
>   And that's why **the tree**
>   Will **continue to be**
>   Since **observed** by, Yours **faithfully**, God.

God's reply is that (s)he is **always present** *(always about in the quad)* and therefore **the tree lives** *(continues to be)*.  (S)he closes using **observed** and **faithfully**

> **Observance** and **faith** are religious codes words for **piety**.

On the surface the limerick is saying **God is ever present**.

At a deeper level, Knox may be saying that

> **God knows more than man can comprehend**

no matter the **learned education**

Knox's writings are considered to be **witty** and **eloquent** and usually calls into question Catholic doctrine.